# Laravel Livewire + Firefox: wire:submit.prevent not working, form submitted as GET request

Tags: laravel, firefox, laravel-livewire

I have a problem when submitting form in Laravel Livewire and when using Firefox. It works well in Chrome. In Firefox - it sometimes works correctly and submits the form through livewire, but mostly it gets submitted as GET request - `https://example.com/?formResponse=...`

Here's a short snippet of my code.

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="update" class="d-flex">
  <textarea name="formResponse" wire:model.defer="formResponse" id="response" class="form-control h-50"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Uložiť</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you loadedd the Livewire scripts, and checked that there are no error-messages in the console (or that appears when you submit - you can set your console to not clear messages on redirects).

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Uložiť</button>
```